# C function that stops after a specified amount of time in milliseconds

Tags: c, ubuntu, time, time.h

I wrote a code for this but it is not working. This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

long timediff(clock_t t1, clock_t t2) {
    long elapsed;
    elapsed = ((double)t2 - t1) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC * 1000;
    return elapsed;
}

int main(void) {
    clock_t t1, t2;
    int i;
    long elapsed;

    long settime = 9;   
    t1 = clock();
    for (i=0; i > 10000000; i++) {
           t2 = clock();
       elapsed = timediff(t1, t2);
           if (elapsed==settime)
                 printf("set time reached\n");
        break;
    }



    printf("elapsed: %ld ms\n", elapsed);


    return 0;
}
```

For some reason, it isnt executing the if statement. The only thing that I can see printed to the terminal is `elapsed: 4195440 ms`. I need to be able to specify how long I want the program to run for before it get's cut.

For example, the way i want this code to run is, I set the settime to be 5 such that after 5 milliseconds, the code stops and the 'set time reached' message is printed to the terminal. I am not sure if this is important but I am using the Ubuntu OS.

Comment: Does it work if you put `(elapsed>=settime)` instead of `(elapsed==settime)`? I fear it might just step "over" your preset value.

Comment: @Blaze Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately, that does not work. It still prints `elapsed: 4195968 ms`.

Comment: Also that `break` is not part of the `if` statement.

Comment: `for (i=0; i > 10000000; i++) ` should be     `for (i=0; i < 10000000; i++) ` otherwise control does not enter loop only. Also `10000000` is too large for integer.

Comment: @kiranBiradar: "*Also 10000000 is too large for integer.*" Well, I'd say Ubuntu is at least 32 bit, so an `int` typically goes up to 2'147'483'647.

Comment: @alk my mistake just considered 16bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include `break` inside the body of `if`

```
                 if (elapsed==settime)
                 {printf("set time reached\n");
                 break;}
```

As suggested in the comment section, you should change the for loop condition otherwise it won't execute. Change this `for (i=0; i > 10000000; i++)` to `for (i=0; i < 10000000; i++)`

Comment: I'd tested for `elapsed >= settime`!

Answer (score 1):

Check the positinion of the instruction `break;` It should be in the `if` block!
also the sign in the `for` loop; must be `i<1000000`

Answer (score 0):

`clock()` just can’t register work that takes a small amount of time. This is pretty unexpected as clock() should return the processor time used by the program. The resolution depends on the OS but is usually between 10 and 16 ms.

In your code wee see `long settime = 9;`. This means you expect to stop at 9 ms which is less than the 10ms resolution of `clock()`.

A workaround would be to change the following code :

```
if (elapsed==settime)
      printf("set time reached\n");
break;
```

to

```
if (elapsed>=settime) {
        printf("set time reached\n");
        break;
}
```